# Chemfig - Forced departure and arrival atoms

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I draw two different molceules for my thesis in ChemFig.

```
\chemname{\chemfig{H_{2}N-[1]*6(=N-*5(-N(>*5(-O-(<-[4]O-[5]P(-[2]O)(-[3])=O)-(<:O-)-(<:OH)-))-=N-)=-(=O)-HN-)}}{molecule X}
```

```
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(=N-*5(-N(>*5(-O-([-3]<-[3]S^{+}(-[2]\textcolor{red}{H_3C})-[-3]-[3]-[-3]C([-2]<NH_2)-[3]([2]=O)-[-3]O^{-})-(<:OH)-(<:OH)-))-=N-)=-(-H_{2}N)=N-)}}{molecule Y}
```

[image: The right molecule is ok but I cannot rotate the upper left one without resulting in faulty connection to the N atom (red circle).]

The right molecule is ok but I cannot rotate the upper left one without resulting in faulty connection to the N atom (red circle).

I tried for ours but cannot find the reason why it is not working. Also http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf could not provide a proper answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{H_{2}N-[:30]*6(=N-*5(-N(>*5(-O-(<-[4]O-[5]P(-[2]O)(-[3])=O)-(<:O-)-(<:OH)-))-=N-)=-(=O)-HN-[,,2])}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thanks that worked. I now tried to add a negative charge to the oxygen. And it becomes offcenter. It does not work by using an optinal argument. [:90,,1,1,] instead of [2]                                                                                                            \chemfig{H_{2}N-[:30]*6(=N-*5(-N(>*5(-O-(<-[4]O-[5]P(-[2]O^{-})(-[3])=[-2]O)-(<:O-)-(<:OH)-))-=N-)=-(=O)-HN-[,,2])}

Comment: Got it O\rlap{${}^-$} does the trick.

Comment: better with command `\charge`

`\chemfig{H_{2}N-[:30]*6(=N-*5(-N(>*5(-O-(<-[4]O-[5]P(-[2]\charge{45:1pt=$\scriptstyle-$}{O})(-[3])=[-2]O)-(<:O-)-(<:OH)-))-=N-)=-(=O)-HN-[,,2])} `